# Restrict Access to Accounts based on a pick list value

Tags: picklist, account-management

We have a pick list field in Account object. Values of the picklist are X and Y. Now I would like to hide or restrict access to records which have picklist value as X for certain profile called Operations. So this profile users should be able to see only records with picklist value Y but not X.

I have tried different ways but could not get it. Any insights could be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make Account OWD = Private
2. Create Account sharing setting i.e,

Based on criteria - Pick list = y --> Assign for group of users/Public Groups/roles.

Answer (score 2):

If you set up two record types you'd effectively be doing the same thing as you're asking. Make only the one RecordType available to the Operations Profile and the other either read-only or no access. You can then simply edit the record type (a picklist) to allow or disallow access to those users. You can find out more about RecordTypes by searching on it in the Salesforce Help.

Comment: I already have all the records in the org. Now based on picklist value can I restrict the access to specific account records?

Comment: how many picklist values are you expecting to have?

Comment: 4 picklist values. Operations profile should be able to see only one picklist value account records. Remaining all the records should be hidden from them.

Comment: Each account would have a record type on it. Changing the RecordType would change who had access to the record depending on what profile had the recordtype enabled for it.

Comment: Record type sharing setting is done. That is for different values. Now after that I would like to restrict access to accounts based on a pick list field value.

Comment: Please edit your original question then to explain your current use of record types and your sharing model as well as your use of profiles and groups. It would appear that the answer to your question is not as simple as you originally presented it since you didn't provide the amount of information needed to give an answer that fits your particular situation.